# Remove duplicates from multiple cells of a column seperated by "|"

Tags: linux

I want to remove duplicates from multiple cells of the column 5 with delimiter "|".  The data I have looks like this:

```
   Col1     Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

1048563  93750984   5   0.499503476 HTR7|HTR7|HTR7

1048564  93751210   5   0.499503476 ABHD3|ABHD3|ABHD3|ABHD3|ABHD3|ABHD3

1048566  93751298   5   0.499503476 ADCYAP1|ADCYAP1|ADCYAP1|ADCYAP1

And I want the result to be:

   Col1 Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

1048563 93750984    5   0.499503476 HTR7

1048564 93751210    5   0.499503476 ABHD3

1048566 93751298    5   0.499503476 ADCYAP1
```

The number of rows and columns are different.The length of the text in column 5 is not always the same

Comment: Do your rows have always the same number of columns?

Comment: `sed 's/,\(.*\)\(|\1\)\+$/,\1/g'`? Or simply `cut -d'|' -f1` or `sed 's/|.*$//g'`? The requirements aren’t particularly clear.

Comment: In case the total length is always the same, you might use this information.

Comment: No, the lenght is not the same

Comment: Biffen .. cut -d'|' -f1 works  . Thanks a lot

Comment: Sounds like a homework question... [How do I ask homework questions on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+ask+homework+questions+on+Stack+Overflow). You are expected to make an effort.